# Def in renewenvironment

Tags: environments

I redefine a custom environment of mine that uses "local variables":

```
\newenvironment{asdf}[3]{
  \def\argi{#1}
  \def\argii{#2}
  \def\argiii{#3}
  %....
}
{ }
```

But when I do:

```
\renewenvironment{asdf}[3]{
  \def\argi{#1}
  \def\argii{#2}
  \def\argiii{#3}
  %....
}
{ }
```

later on in the document, LaTeX claims

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \test
```

And also, I have no idea where `\test` comes from.

Comment: Will's answer shows that in such cases you should always include a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/1235), not just the code snippet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I redefine a custom environment of mine that uses "local variables":
\newenvironment{asdf}[3]{
  \def\argi{#1}
  \def\argii{#2}
  \def\argiii{#3}
  %....
}
{ }
But when I do:
\renewenvironment{asdf}[3]{
  \def\argi{#1}
  \def\argii{#2}
  \def\argiii{#3}
  %....
}
{ }
\end{document}
```

I suspect here's more you're not telling us, such as that you have the `\renewenvironment` inside something else. Don't forget that if you have `\renewenvironment` inside another macro, you need to double the `#` signs:

```
\def\reset{%
  \renewenvironment{asdf}[3]{
    \def\argi{##1}
    \def\argii{##2}
    \def\argiii{##3}
  }
  { }
}
```

Comment: Would `\def\foo{\def\bar{\renewenvironment{asdf}[3]...` require `###1`?

Comment: @Seamus: No, `####1`; you have to _double_ each `#`.